# How can I do majority voting with a multiplexer?

Tags: multiplexer, homework, proteus

My homework is to make:

- Majority voting
- 8 members
- In the event of a tie, the president's word counts for two
- In Proteus with a multiplexer

In the pictures you can see what I have achieved so far. I don't know if this is correct or if I'm on the right track to a solution. How would you solve this voting circuit with a multiplexer, what do you think I did wrong, what should be improved?

I have to do it with a multiplexer. The type and quantity of the multiplexer are not specified.

[image]

Comment: You mean 5 out of 8 have to agree (excluding a tie here)?  And that order doesn't matter?

Comment: Why with a multiplexer? Use the right tool for the job: a microprocessor and software. If for some reason you won't do software, then do it in analog: two D/A converters and a comparator.

Comment: (@DavideAndrea analogue is tempting but *without* an 8 or more bit DAC. Just *something* and a one bit ADC: a comparator.)(Why two DACs, anyway?)

Comment: One for the red voters, one for the blue voters. The "D/A" is just a set of resistors all of the same value, not a binary to analog converter.

Comment: Please explain why a multiplexer has to be used (as per your previous question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/648965/how-make-8-member-majority-voting-with-a-multiplexer)

Comment: I also don't understand why it has to be done with a multiplexer, but it says this in the task and I have to do it with a multiplexer. I don't know how to do it correctly with a multiplexer.

Comment: The quantity and type of the multiplexer are not specified. According to them, you can use as much and as much as you want.

Comment: I would be tempted to do analog summing amplifier + comparator.

Comment: There are several tasks, someone has to do this with a decoder. Unfortunately for me with a multiplexer.

Comment: True, I forgot that. But I will improve on this as well.

Comment: A 2:1 multiplexer is a universal gate after all... You can theoretically build any logic with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As any boolean function this is trivial using a table/a multiplexer of appropriate size. Here, a \$2^8\$ to 1 multiplexer:
1 president and 7 more members as selection bits, multiplexer inputs tied to H & L as appropriate.
Or 17 16-to-1 multiplexers connected accordingly, smaller ones left as an exercise.

Just a weird implementation of a 256*1 bit random access memory, writeable or not.

Comment: So can this voting logic be solved with a 256:1 multiplexer?

Comment: If it is *president+7 members*: yes. Guess what you'd need for *president+8 members*. (Work out *president+3 members*.)

Comment: I would also like to ask how I can solve it so that in case of a tie the vote of the president is worth 2, otherwise only 1?

Comment: (Equivalently, president weight 3, other members 2 - unconditionally.) Work out *president+3 members*!

Comment: (when you have *president+3 members* worked out and think it would improve this answer: Edit it!)

Answer (score 1):

That analogue solution hinted at several times.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fynwt3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: (Try and figure out min.  #voters such that ±5% precision resistors might lead to a wrong result.)

Comment: That's pretty neat